# What is the file format of "EGM2008 - WGS 84 Version" available from NGA site?

Tags: file, format

What is the file format of "EGM2008 - WGS 84 Version" 2.5 x 2.5-Minute Geoid Undulation Grid in WGS 84 - SMALL ENDIAN product [available here](http://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/wgs84/gravitymod/egm2008/)?

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe that's what you're looking for (§4):
[README_WGS84 (pdf)](http://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/wgs84/gravitymod/egm2008/README_WGS84_2.pdf)

Comment: _is there any way i can read **EGM2008_to2190_TideFree.gz ** file using python?_

Comment: you should first decompress the file with gunzip, then use the numpy function fromfile with the option dtype='>f4' to match the big-endian 4 bytes float encoding